# How to tell if only one finger touching in Microsoft IE10

Tags: javascript, touch, internet-explorer-10

We are emulating scrolling of an infinite list and we wish to detect the difference between a single finger scrolling, or the user starting a gesture.

In theory one can keep a count of fingers down in IE10 by +1 for every `MSPointerDown` and -1 for `MSPointerUp` events (and/or matching fingers using the event.msPointerId).

In practice, there is at least one bug where IE10 will generate an MSPointerDown event but never ever send the matching MSPointerUp event. (Sorry, I haven't been able to create a simple test case to show this, but I did spend a lot of time checking that the MSPointerUp event is *definitely* missing. Maybe due to removal of child elements during the touch).

Perhaps use the MSGesture events to see if multiple fingers are down? (I tried this with little success, but maybe someone else has solved it).

Any ideas?

PS: In webkit the equivalent is to check `event.touches.length === 1` in the touchstart event (beware that you need an unobvious trick to get this working: document.ontouchstart must have an event registered, and then event.touches.length will be correct for touchstart events registered on *other* elements).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are also keeping track of MSPointerOut. I've found that MSPointerUp will not be called if you let go of the screen whilst outside of the trackable area.

If it helps, I've got a WinJS class I've been using to track multitouch state.

```
var TouchState = WinJS.Class.define(
function () {
    this.pointers = [];
    this.primaryPointerId = 0;

    this.touchzones = [];
}, {
    touchHandler: function (eventType, e) {
        if (eventType == "MSPointerDown") {
            if (!this.pointers[this.primaryPointerId] || !this.pointers[this.primaryPointerId].touching) {
                this.primaryPointerId = e.pointerId;
            }
            e.target.msSetPointerCapture(e.pointerId);
            this.pointers[e.pointerId] = {
                touching: true,
                coords: {
                    x: e.currentPoint.rawPosition.x,
                    y: e.currentPoint.rawPosition.y
                }
            };
            this.checkTouchZones(this.pointers[e.pointerId].coords.x, this.pointers[e.pointerId].coords.y, e);
        }
        else if (eventType == "MSPointerMove") {
            if (this.pointers[e.pointerId]) {
                this.pointers[e.pointerId].coords.x = e.currentPoint.rawPosition.x;
                this.pointers[e.pointerId].coords.y = e.currentPoint.rawPosition.y;
            }
        }
        else if (eventType == "MSPointerUp") {
            if (this.pointers[e.pointerId]) {
                this.pointers[e.pointerId].touching = false;
                this.pointers[e.pointerId].coords.x = e.currentPoint.rawPosition.x;
                this.pointers[e.pointerId].coords.y = e.currentPoint.rawPosition.y;                    
            }
        }
        else if (eventType == "MSPointerOut") {
            if (this.pointers[e.pointerId]) {
                this.pointers[e.pointerId].touching = false;
                this.pointers[e.pointerId].coords.x = e.currentPoint.rawPosition.x;
                this.pointers[e.pointerId].coords.y = e.currentPoint.rawPosition.y;
            }
        }
    },
    checkTouchZones: function (x, y, e) {
        for (var zoneIndex in this.touchzones) {
            var zone = this.touchzones[zoneIndex];
            if (x >= zone.hitzone.x1 && x < zone.hitzone.x2 && y > zone.hitzone.y1 && y < zone.hitzone.y2) {
                zone.callback(e);
            }
        }
    },
    addTouchZone: function (id, hitzone, callback) {
        this.touchzones[id] = {
            hitzone: hitzone,
            callback: callback
        };
    },
    removeTouchZone: function (id) {
        this.touchzones[id] = null;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I will have to try that.